# MongoDB, получить посты за определенный период времени

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Как получить посты, например, запрошлый месяц, сортировку я знаю как делать а конкретную дату, нет.

Спасибо.

---

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {

  Post.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .limit(5)
    .then(posts => {
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

---

[image: получить эти посты]

Comment: `Post.find({date : {$gte : new Date("2019-07-01"), $lt : new Date("2019-08-01"}})`.

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо!